# PySpark Error in File handling and data manipulation

Tags: python, pyspark

I am having a tough time working with PySpark.
I am trying to read csv files and do a one-hot encoding (for now).

I get an error that spans 2 pages.

My sample code is given below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
shirtsize = sc.textFile("shirt_sizes.*")
shirt_header = shirtsize.first()
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(),True) for field_name in shirt_header.split(',')]

fields[0].dataType = IntegerType()
schema = StructType(fields)
shirtDF = spark.createDataFrame(shirtsize,schema)
SI = StringIndexer(inputCol="ethcty",outputCol="ET_out")
model = SI.fit(shirtDF)
```

The error is too long but this is the beginning :

```
17/10/13 15:22:38 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 
1.0 (TID 1, cluster-a2db-m.c.internal, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api
.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 520, in prepare
    verify_func(obj, schema)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1366, in _verify_type
    raise TypeError("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s" % (obj, type(obj)))
TypeError: StructType can not accept object u'columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD....' in type <type 'unicode'>
```

There is some Type error that I am not able to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `csv` reader:

```
spark.read.schema(schema).format("csv").load(path)\
```

Otherwise you have to parse all the lines first (split and create `Rows` / `tuples` and cast values to expected types).